# Calling and executing a stored procedure from sql into a vb.net textbox

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have created the following stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
CREATE Procedure CalcTotal
    @InvoiceID Varchar(4)
As
    Declare @Total int
Begin
    SELECT 
       @Total = (TransportFee + EquipmentFee + LabourFee) 
    FROM 
       Invoice 
    WHERE 
       InvoiceID = @invoiceID

    UPDATE Invoice 
    SET Total = @Total 
    WHERE InvoiceID = @invoiceID
END
```

My code for my form on Visual Basic are:

```
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Invoice
    Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Hamsheed;Initial Catalog=assignment;Integrated Security=True"}
    Dim sqlstr As String = "Select * From Invoice"
    Dim MaxRows As Integer
    Dim RowIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim dt As New DataTable



    Private Sub Invoice_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim DataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlstr, sqlConn)
        DataAdapter.Fill(dt)
        DataAdapter.Dispose()
        MaxRows = dt.Rows.Count
        InvoiceDetails()
        cmbSearch.DataSource = dt
        cmbSearch.DisplayMember = "FirstName"

    End Sub

    Sub InvoiceDetails()

        txtInvoiceID.Text = CStr(dt.Rows(RowIndex)("InvoiceID"))
        txtClientID.Text = CStr(dt.Rows(RowIndex)("ClientID"))
        txtEmployeeID.Text = CStr(dt.Rows(RowIndex)("EmployeeID"))
        txtFillInDate.Text = CStr(dt.Rows(RowIndex)("FillInDate"))
        txtTransportFee.Text = CStr(dt.Rows(RowIndex)("TransportFee"))
        txtEquipmentFee.Text = CStr(dt.Rows(RowIndex)("EquipmentFee"))
        txtLabourFee.Text = CStr(dt.Rows(RowIndex)("LabourFee"))
        txtTotal.Text = CStr(dt.Rows(RowIndex)("Total"))
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click


        Dim InvoiceID As String = txtInvoiceID.Text
        Dim ClientID As String = txtClientID.Text
        Dim EmployeeID As String = (txtEmployeeID.Text)
        Dim FillInDate As Date = CDate(txtFillInDate.Text)
        Dim TransportFee As Integer = CInt(txtTransportFee.Text)
        Dim EquipmentFee As Integer = CInt(txtEquipmentFee.Text)
        Dim LabourFee As Integer = CInt(txtLabourFee.Text)
        Dim Total As Integer = CInt(txtTotal.Text)




        If CStr(dt.Rows(RowIndex)("paymentmethod")) = "Card" Then

            radCard.Select()

        ElseIf CStr(dt.Rows(RowIndex)("paymentmethod")) = "Cash" Then
            radCash.Select()

        Else
            radCredit.Select()
        End If


        Dim sqlQuery As String = ("Exec Insert_Invoice @InvoiceID = ' " & InvoiceID & " ', @ClientID = '" & ClientID & "',@EmployeeID ='" & EmployeeID & "', @FillInDate ='" & FillInDate & "',@TransportFee='" & TransportFee & "',@EquipmentFee = '" & EquipmentFee & "',@LabourFee= '" & LabourFee & "',@Total= '" & Total)

        Dim sqlcmnd As New SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn)

        Try
            sqlConn.Open()
            Dim changes As Integer = sqlcmnd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sqlConn.Close()
            MessageBox.Show(changes & "Changes Made")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Save()

    End Sub


    Private Sub btnEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
        dt.Rows(RowIndex)("InvoiceID") = CStr(txtInvoiceID.Text)
        dt.Rows(RowIndex)("ClientID") = CStr(txtClientID.Text)
        dt.Rows(RowIndex)("EmployeeID") = CStr(txtEmployeeID.Text)
        dt.Rows(RowIndex)("FillInDate") = CStr(txtFillInDate.Text)
        dt.Rows(RowIndex)("TransportFee") = CStr(txtTransportFee.Text)
        dt.Rows(RowIndex)("EquipmentFee") = CStr(txtEquipmentFee.Text)
        dt.Rows(RowIndex)("LabourFee") = CStr(txtLabourFee.Text)
        dt.Rows(RowIndex)("Total") = CStr(txtTotal.Text)
        Dim sqlquery As String = "exec edit_invoice '" & txtInvoiceID.Text & "', " & txtLabourFee.Text & ", " & txtTransportFee.Text & ", " & txtEquipmentFee.Text & ", '" & txtpaymentMethod.Text & "', '" & txtClientID.Text & "', '" & txtEmployeeID.Text & "', '" & txtFillInDate.Text & "', '" & txtTotal.Text & "'"

        Dim sqlcmnd As New SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlConn)

        Try
            sqlConn.Open()
            Dim changes As Integer = sqlcmnd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sqlConn.Close()
            MessageBox.Show(changes & "Changes Made")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Save()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        txtInvoiceID.Clear()
        txtClientID.Clear()
        txtEmployeeID.Clear()
        txtFillInDate.Clear()
        txtTransportFee.Clear()
        txtEquipmentFee.Clear()
        txtLabourFee.Clear()
        txtTotal.Clear()



    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        If RowIndex <> MaxRows - 1 Then
            RowIndex += 1
            InvoiceDetails()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLast_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLast.Click
        RowIndex = MaxRows - 1
        InvoiceDetails()

    End Sub


    Private Sub btnMainMenu_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMainMenu.Click
        SecretaryMainMenu.Show()
        Me.Hide()


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click

        Dim invoiceID As String = txtInvoiceID.Text
        Dim SqlQuery As String = ("EXECUTE Delete_Invoice @InvoiceID = '" & InvoiceID & "'")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(SqlQuery, sqlConn)
        Try
            sqlConn.Open()
            Dim changes As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sqlConn.Close()
            MessageBox.Show(changes & "Record Deleted")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Save()

        dt.Rows(RowIndex).Delete()

    End Sub

    Sub Save()

        Dim dataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlstr, sqlConn)
        Dim commandbuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter)
        dataAdapter.Update(dt)
        dataAdapter.Dispose()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnFind_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFind.Click
        Dim searchitem As String = InputBox("Input Search invoice ID: ", "Search by ID")
        Dim sresult As Boolean = False
        searchitem = searchitem.Trim.ToUpper

        For i As Integer = 0 To MaxRows - 1
            If CStr(dt.Rows(i)("invoiceid")).ToUpper = searchitem Then
                sresult = True
                RowIndex = i
                InvoiceDetails()
            End If
        Next

        If sresult = False Then
            MsgBox("No result found", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Information")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtinvoice_validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles txtInvoiceID.Validating
        If Not txtInvoiceID.Text Like "I###" Then
            e.Cancel = True
            ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtInvoiceID, "Improper ID format")

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtinvoice_validated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles txtInvoiceID.Validated
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtInvoiceID, "")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now I want to call the stored procedure into the textbox Total, which will compute the 'transportFee, EquipmentFee and Labourfee' costs, and display the total into the textbox of txtTotal.Text

How do I write that piece of code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: I don't think this question indicates _what_ the problem was, and it has since been abandoned, so I am recommending that it is put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

use executescalar: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

remember to set the commandtype property of the command to stored procedure